# Navigation quickly disappearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. My navigation dropdown quickly disappears when you're trying to hover over the menu. How can I possibly delay the disappearance of the navigation by some miliseconds/seconds?
2. Again, say when you hover over the `menu` (e.g. sub-item 0.1 etc) of `Folder 1/Folder 2`, I want it  will have a blue color to show that it's active.

Please check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgyeB/) to see the JS, CSS, and HTML.

going ahead and editing this `fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 2000}`in the js only changes the animation speed. But THAT IS NOT what I want. I'm talking about the `DURATION` the menu exist before disappearing not the `speed of the animation`

Answer (score 0):

the variable you pass to the function ( it has 100 ms fadeout )

make it 300

`outduration: 300`

`fadesettings: {overduration: 350, outduration: 400}, //duration of fade in/ out`

as for colors you can add them with css:

```
.elementclass:hover {
     background-color:#0000FF; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: +1 for not getting side-tracked by a crushing wall of script. Changing that outduration did increase the time.

Comment: Have you tried what you're talking about in a fiddle? Doesn't work. The navigation animation just slows down. Again, about the hover, Please read my question again. It seems you didn't get it. Nice attempt though.  :/

Comment: what you did just changed the speed of the fadeIn fadeOut animation. Does not what I want. I mean the duration before the menu dissapears not the ANIMATION SPEED

Comment: @Anonymous what is so difficult to understand? Try putting what you've typed in a fiddle as he said and you'll see it doesn't work the way she wants it.